# Google Autocomplete, when clicked location it calls Google Places

Tags: google-places, google-places-autocomplete

I have a directive that calls `google.maps.places.Autocomplete`:

```
var options = {
    fields: ['formatted_address']
  };

scope.gPlace = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(element[0], options);
google.maps.event.addListener(scope.gPlace, 'place_changed', function() {
      scope.$apply(function() {
        model.$setViewValue(element.val());
      });
    });
```

Image 1
[image: Image 1]

Image 2
[image: Image 2]

In Image 1 you will see the network call that I get as I type, which is fine, but on Image 2 you will see another network call to Google Places that's triggered when I click on the location that I want.

I only want the location that's clicked, not all that data. It's costing me too much. Is there a way I can avoid calling Google Places on click of autocomplete?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify to retrieve only the `Geometry` field but using the Autocomplete Widget from Google, you can't avoid calling Google Places getDetails on prediction item click.

```js
scope.gPlace = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(element[0], options);
scope.gPlace.setFields(['geometry']);
scope.gPlace.addListener('place_changed', function() {
    const place = autocomplete.getPlace();
    //console.log(place.geometry.location);
  });
```

To reduce your cost, you could use the Google Geocoding API to retrieve address information (location) instead of `getDetails()` from Autocomplete.
You'll need to implement `AutocompleteService` instead of the `Autocomplete` Widget.

I've wrote a [blog post](https://blog.woosmap.com/implement-and-optimize-autocomplete-with-google-places-api) to explain how to implement this feature and a lot of others tips and tricks to reduce the cost of your Google Maps Autocomplete feature.